# Как можно сделать два в одном слайдере с использованием slick?

Tags: slider, slick.js

Дизайнер нарисовал слайдер-матрешку. В одном слайдере есть еще один. Я реализовывала все это с использованием slick.js, но на мобильном сайте когда ты скролишь блок с внутренним слайдером перелистывается основной. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно избежать этого или может посоветуете другой слайдер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно отключить свайп для внешнего слайдера на мобильных разрешениях:

```js
$(function() {
  $('.slider').slick({
    responsive: [
      {
        breakpoint: 900, // замените на нужное вам значение, аналог медиа-запроса (max-width: 900px)
        settings: {
          swipe: false
        }
      }
    ]
  });
  
  $('.slider-inner').slick();
})
```

```css
.slide {
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link rel=stylesheet href=https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.6.0/slick.min.css />
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slide">1</div>
  <div class="slide">
    <div class="slider-inner">
      <div class="slide">1</div>
      <div class="slide">2</div>
      <div class="slide">3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slide">3</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я тоже пришла к такому решению)